# Load yaml file as dict

Tags: python, dictionary, yaml

I have a YAML file that stores username and their ssh-keys.. it looks like this:

```
---
- bjones:
   name: Bob Jones
   ssh_keys:
   - "ssh-rsa dsgdsgds"
   - "ssh-rsa gdgsadg"
   - "ssh-rsa sagagsa"

- jsmith:
   name: Jimmy Smith
   ssh_keys:
   - "ssh-rsa gjdgjas"
```

I want to bring that into some python as a dict but not sure how.

```
In [98]: data = yaml.safe_load(open("/user-list.yaml"))
In [99]: type(data)
Out[99]: list
```

Where do I go from here to make this a dict?

I need the first user with multiple ssh-keys for the keys to be in a list on newlines as well

Comment: So, right now you have `[{'bjones': {...}}, {'jsmith': {...}}]`; do you want `{'bjones': {...}, 'jsmith': {...}}` instead?

Comment: That would just be `{k: v for d in data for k, v in d.items()}`.

Comment: yah this works.  I need to learn more about dict comprehension

Answer (score 1):

The original markup *is* a list of dicts - but you can chain these dicts together:

```
>>> from collections import ChainMap
>>> result = ChainMap(*data)
>>> result["jsmith"]
{'name': 'Jimmy Smith', 'ssh_keys': ['ssh-rsa gjdgjas']}
```

If you're sure there are no duplicate entries in the original markup, i.e. `len(data) == len(result)`, then you can safely convert it back into a single dict with `dict(result)`.